# Flask-security and Bootstrap

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-login, flask-security

How can I style my Flask-security login site with Bootstrap? The html form looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_form">
  {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email) }}
  {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
  {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
  {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
  {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
</form>
```

Bootstrap is implemented, but I dont know how to edit the fields and the submit button..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `render_field_*` functions accepts a `class_` parameter, which will add HTML classes to the field. Add in bootstrap styling classes as you want.

```
render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, class_="form-control") }}
{{ render_field(login_user_form.submit, class_="btn btn-default") }}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 6):

Flask-Security uses Flask-WTForms to render and validate forms. In Flask-Security 1.7.5, the default `render_field_with_errors` and `render_field` macros defined in "security/_macros.html" are

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors(field) %}
  <p>
    {{ field.label }} {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <p>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

According to the [Flask-WTForms 0.10 docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates), both of the above macro functions accept ...

> ... keyword arguments that are forwarded to WTForm’s field function that renders the field for us. The keyword arguments will be inserted as HTML attributes.

Specifically, the lines {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }} pass the HTML escaped keyword arguments to the field function. Therefore, you can add classes,

```
{{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, class="form-control") }}
```

and can also overwrite default HTML attributes,

```
{{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, 
    class="form-control", type="email", placeholder="Enter email") }}
{{ render_field(login_user_form.submit, class="btn btn-default", value="Submit" ) }}
```

Additionally, you can **define your own macros** by modifying the macros above. For example, if you wanted to use Bootstrap alerts to render form validation errors, you could define the macro function `render_field_with_bootstrap_errors`

```
{% macro render_field_with_bootstrap_errors(field) %}
  <p>
    {{ field.label }} {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ error }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </p>
{% endmacro %}
```

Adding your own macro is pretty simple. For example, you can put custom macros in a "custom_macros.html" file within the templates directory and then load the functions into templates with

```
{% from "custom_macros.html" import render_field_with_bootstrap_errors %}
```

This way, it is easy to modify the macros to use different Bootstrap features.